# Calling Mixpanel Alias and Identify events in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, mixpanel

I am trying to call the Mixpanel alias and identify events into hooks for user_registration and wp_login but am getting undefined function errors on the alias function on registration and identify function on login.

I have included the Mixpanel javascript in my header and below are my two hooks that I am using in my functions.php file.

Any help on what I may be doing wrong here would be greatly appreciated!

```js
// MIXPANEL REGISTRATION SCRIPT
function mixpanelRegistration($user_id) {
    mixpanel.alias($user_id);
}
add_action('user_register', 'mixpanelRegistration');


// MIXPANEL LOGIN SCRIPT
function mixpanelLogin($user) {
    mixpanel.identify($user->ID);
}
add_action('wp_login', 'mixpanelLogin');
```

Comment: If you are using mixpanel javascript library then you will need to use mixpanel in javascript not php. Otherwise use php library for mixpanel.

Comment: @PrajwalBati this was exactly my issue thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was being caused by trying to call the mixpanel javascript library within my WordPress functions (PHP). Ended up needing to call in the mixpanel php library.